# MVC jquery call action controller not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some jquery shown below required to run my mvc action and return the view.

```
   $("#workspaces").change(function () {
    var workspaceId = $('#workspaces').val();
    var url = '@Url.Action("SingleWorkspace", "Workspaces", new { id = workspaceId })';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function () { alert("true"); }
    });
});
```

Basically the first issue i have is that it does not recognise the workspaceId within the url action if though the var is declared above it.

Secondly this is within a partial view as it is a dropdown menu. So by calling the url.action above how would it load the page?

any help would be appreciated

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
var workspaceId = $('#workspaces').val();
var url = '@Url.Action("SingleWorkspace", "Workspaces", new { id = "__id__" })'
    .replace('__id__', workspaceId);
```

Comment: I preferred this method. It worked a treat. On success I basically used the window.location.href = 'the url here' which redirected me to the page i needed to be on

Answer (score 0):

```
   var workspaceId = $('#workspaces').val();  
   var url = '@Url.Action("SingleWorkspace", "Workspaces", new { id = workspaceId })';
```

`Url.Action` - is server code (ASP.NET MVC helper) and `workspaceId` selected on client, that's why `url` can't be created here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `workspaceId` is defined on the client, whereas the `@Url.Action` is run on the server so the variable doesn't exist at the point that the `@Url.Action` code executes. You want to send the `workSpaceId` as the data property of the jQuery ajax call instead or append the `workspaceId` to the url javascript variable instead on the client.

Secondly, if the action returns a partial view for example, then the jQuery success handler will receive an html string which you can inject into an element such as a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do like that in javascript. What you can do is to get the path to `SingleWorkSpace` action method and append the `workspaceId` to that.

```
var url = "@Url.Action("SingleWorkspace", "Workspaces")/"+workspaceId;
```

or

```
var url = "@Url.Action("SingleWorkspace", "Workspaces")?id="+workspaceId;
```